# Where to include 'require' statement in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, require

I am trying to use the parse-ruby-client gem in my Rails app. However, I'm not sure where to place the require statement and create statement.

I put

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'

Parse.create :application_id => "<your_app_id>", # required
             :api_key        => "<your_api_key>" # required
```

in application.rb however when I call

```
game_score = client.object("GameScore")
```

I get an error from the app. I'm guessing it is because I'm not putting it in the right place. Any advice on where this should be placed?

Comment: have you included it into your GemFile?

Comment: Yes, I've included it in my gemfile and ran bundle install.

Comment: You can put `require` anywhere, really, but by custom, `require` is listed at the top of a file. Now you say "I get an error from the app." Do you think it would help your case to indicate exactly what that error was?

Comment: I guess you need to put the init code into a initialization file.. inside you lib directory.

Comment: @sharataka please print your error .....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When and where do I require files in a rails application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120824/when-and-where-do-i-require-files-in-a-rails-application)